I need to run two separate VPN clients simultaneously on Windows 11. Fails for me. Works for coworkers
VPN clients are  FortiCLient 7.2.4.0972 and NetExtender 10.2.339.
Two hosts: one for db access and the other for web API access. Split tunneling is not used.
When I connect both (in any order), sending a request to either location succeeds 10% of the time, but causes the unused VPN connection to drop, then the current VPN client drops due to the network change.
I have reviewed the configuration of another Windows 11 system that works with the two VPN clients. It uses both VPN clients simultaneously, and correctly routing the requests to each (or trying them in series?): within Visual Studio, db reqs go over FortiClient, and API reqs are handled by NetExtender.
Coworkers say they have no special setup, no subnets, etc. Just installed VPN client apps and entered host and auth info, just like me.
Help is appreciated.

BTW, Split tunnel is not an option. And not set up on the boxes that 'work'.

Sounds like a question for whoever hosts the VPNs and/or the IT support in your workplace, since no one can tell how exactly the setup looks like, like what's the client conf, whether or not they depend on each other, what routes do they push / configure. You'll at least need to provide some conf files, logs, and maybe the route table. (It might be offtopic on this particular SE site anyway though.)

Honestly, given the description split tunnel is a MUST HAVE in this case. If both VPNs install default routes (which is the case for non-split tunnel) - it is surely going to cause problems. As indicated in other comment - go ask your IT for help.

This is quite late, but I found a solution. You need to enable the service in Automatic mode from the services.msc list of services called Routing and Remote Access Service.
